# ClassCastException while casting JSONArray into JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

Here is my code snippet:

```
    jArray = jChild.getJSONArray("users");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jObject = (JSONObject) jArray.get(i);    //Exception thrown in this line

}
```

**Edit:**

Logcat:

```
09-30 09:06:23.404: E/AndroidRuntime(4011): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-30 09:06:23.404: E/AndroidRuntime(4011):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
09-30 09:06:23.404: E/AndroidRuntime(4011): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
09-30 09:06:23.404: E/AndroidRuntime(4011):     at com.example.DbAccess.loadMonthView(DbAccess.java:196)
```

This is my jsonArray:

```
 [{"uid":"6","status":"absent","name":"xyz"},{"uid":"7","status":"absent","name":"abc Paul"}]
```

I want to retrieve `JSONObject`  from `JSONArray`.

Comment: can you shows us your json

Comment: Sure..just check the edit.

Comment: Post the Logcat for exception also

Comment: @user2749218 what is jChild

Comment: I hope this is not your full JSON, is it? Because there is no 'key' as 'users' to execute `getJSONArray("users")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ // represents json array node
    {     // represents json obeject node  
        "uid": "6",
        "status": "absent",
        "name": "xyz"
    },
    {
        "uid": "7",
        "status": "absent",
        "name": "abc Paul"
    }
]
```

What you have is a JSONArray. You need to parse the values and get the string.

```
     JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("myjsonstring");
     for(int i=0;i<jr.length();j++)
     {
     JSONOBject jb = jr.getJSONObject(i);
     String uid = jb.getString("uid");
     String status = jb.getString("status");
     String name = jb.getString("name");  
     }
```

Comment: @user2749218 you also had this `JSONObject jObject = (JSONObject) jArray.get(i);` so the problem should be probably here `jArray = jChild.getJSONArray("users")`. Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Your Json file has an array at the top level. When the JSonParser parses it, it's returning it as a JSONArray. You're trying to cast it to a JSONObject instead (which is like a map, or dictionary.) What you need to do is this:

```
Object obj;
try {

    obj = parser.parse(sCurrentLine);
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
    for(obj : jsonArray){//not sure of the exact syntax, I don't have an IDE in front of me.
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)obj;
        JSONObject realTitle = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("0");
        String name = (String) realTitle.get("title");
    }


} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```